# Returning a Column Name Based on Dates

Tags: r

I have a data frame which contains a large number of date columns, and I need to return the column name which contains the oldest date for each row.

I.e. if the starting data is:

```
ID      date1      date2
1    2015-08-01 2015-07-01
2    2015-07-01 2015-05-01
3    2015-06-01 2015-09-01
```

Then the end result should be:

```
  ID      date1      date2 MinDate
1    2015-08-01 2015-07-01   date2
2    2015-07-01 2015-05-01   date2
3    2015-06-01 2015-09-01   date1
```

A manual way of doing this is using if-else loops, however this is very manual.

Is there an automated way which would not mean having to manually code all the column names? Manually creating the if-else loops here would not be practical with the large number of columns I have

Sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = 1:3, 
                 date1 = c(as.Date("2015-08-01"),as.Date("2015-07-01"),as.Date("2015-06-01")), 
                 date2 = c(as.Date("2015-07-01"),as.Date("2015-05-01"),as.Date("2015-09-01")),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Code which generates the above result:

```
df$MinDate <- ifelse(df$date1 < df$date2, "date1", "date2")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a <- array()

for(i in 1:nrow(df))
{
 a[i] = which.min(df[i, 2:ncol(df)])  
}

a
# [1] 2 2 1
```

Comment: Exactly what I was after, and so simple too. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This has been accepted but I ll provide an alternative just for completion. If you only compare Date columns you could do:

```
#a function checking if a column is Date
is.Date <- function(x) inherits(x, 'Date')

#Filter returns a df with the Dates
#and then you choose the min column and return its name
df$MinDate <- apply(Filter(is.Date, df), 1, function(x)  names(x[which.min(as.Date(x))]))
```

Output:

```
> df
  ID      date1      date2 MinDate
1  1 2015-08-01 2015-07-01   date2
2  2 2015-07-01 2015-05-01   date2
3  3 2015-06-01 2015-09-01   date1
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Have a feeling this apply based approach will be quicker than using an array

Comment: Np glad I could help. When you use `apply` you are actually using a for-loop on the inside (as opposed to `lapply` where you run a C implemented for-loop). So, speed-wise it will be pretty much the same. However, This will be more robust since you don't need to specify specific column indices and it is clearer to read (it also returns the names instead of the position). If you want speed as well you could replace `apply` with `lapply` and use indices.

Comment: Suppose i have several date columns (say 5 columns) with some of the column dates missing and i would like to create a column with the sequence of the column names from the earliest to the latest of the dates for each id, how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

The best strategy may be to order you column by date descending then just pick the first row in the column.

```
df[order(as.Date(df$date,format="%d/%m/%Y")),,drop=FALSE]
```